# My student's family won't let her study what she wants

Tags: career-path, international-students

Yesterday I had a tearful encounter in office hours with the most avid participant in the math class I teach, in which she related the following situation.

She is an international student whose parents are well off by local standards but have made significant financial sacrifices for her to study abroad at the university where I work. Part of the plan was that she should have a scholarship, but it has recently been denied on the grounds her grades are not strong enough, and as a result she will have to switch to a nearby university in the fall. Part of why her grades aren't strong is because she is a very specifically focused student: professional mathematics is all she really wants to do with her life. She already knows. When she is able to do what she wants, she just studies math. She works extremely hard, but at end of the day she couldn't care less about her other courses and views the struggle to get good grades as a distraction from what's important to her.

Her parents disagree that there is any future in math for her. They tell her it's not worth it and that she's bad at it. They're medical doctors in a country where teachers are treated poorly, viewed as people lacking the talent to do anything better, and are worried that a career in math would be both unremunerative and undignified—which might be the case in her home country, but my student also doesn't hope to return home. Nevertheless, for because her parents are footing the bill and because she's not willing to openly defy them, my student will finish a pure CS major when she enrolls in her new university, and won't be allowed to enroll in any future math courses during undergrad.

I watched her just crumble as she told me this, weeping and apologizing for it, unable to make eye contact. She's about to embark, without any choice in the matter, on a course that's going to make her miserable for years, if not longer, and moreover, from what I know of her, **she is just the kind of person who should be in math**.

I've told her there's nothing anyone can do to stop her from learning on her own, and that absolutely no instructor would refuse to let her sit in on whatever math course she wants, so that at most this will be a hiccup resulting in her getting a sort of bachelor's degree she doesn't really want at the expense of what she'd rather do, and that at the time she's financially independent, she can really study what she wants, but one could tell she's not completely buying this. She's devastated, and I can hardly blame her.

What can I (or anyone) do to help in this situation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71879/discussion-on-question-by-jdc-my-students-family-wont-let-her-study-what-she-w).

Comment: I went to school for math, and continue to study math at the graduate level. Myself and many of my peers have jobs in software/computer science related fields for one reason or another. I think it's just worth noting that many companies that hire CS majors will also hire math majors for the same jobs, with the same salaries, and often choosing them over those with an educational background in programming. Maybe finding some statistics on this could help convince the parents that a math degree is not a waste of time, and in fact might lead to better paying jobs in the future.

Comment: What's her nationality?

Comment: Please update this page to let us know what happened eventually (say, an update after a year and another one after 5 years if you can manage that).

Comment: "will finish a pure CS major [...] and won't be allowed to enroll in any future math courses" I don't get it. I have a BSc and MSc in CS and I studied **a lot** of math. Computer science is heavily based on math (plus some other things, but still). How is it possible that she won't be able to enroll in math courses? Some of them are even mandatory for graduating in CS.

Comment: Not enough rep to answer -- but I would suggest talking to the scholarship committee and seeing if they'll award to her if she gets her grades up this term (more motivation to get good grades in the other classes). Sounds like if she fixes the financial issue, she can stay at your university...

Comment: Depending on your relationship with the deciding body on her being 'forced out' of this university because of her grades, you may have sway to instead get her placed on academic probation? Having a professor 'going to bat' for her could make a difference (I've seen it happen). She could also apply for student loans at a financial institution.

Comment: I was in the same boat, and I eventually transferred out of the premed major that my parents wanted. I know this type of enormous pressure, and it is not uncommon for students to cave. I would suggest to her this: find a university where it is easy to transfer between majors. Then, she can appease her parents by giving CS a go. Perhaps she will like it, then everyone is happy; or it may strengthen her resolve to return to mathematics, then her parents are more likely to finally accept her aspirations, and ending up with a minor in CS may give her an extra edge.

Comment: @foo There's no such thing as not enough rep to answer. Asking and answering are the two activities that you can always do.

Comment: If you update the answer or tag it with something indicating the student's nationality, you might get better answers, as this seems to be very deeply rooted in the student's family culture.  I don't think you would be revealing too much, there are probably a large number of students from that country in Canada, at many different schools.

Comment: @BenI. There's an exception to that. [Answering a protected question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) requires a minimum amount of rep earned on the same site the question is on before answers can be posted. This question is protected, so all unregistered and some registered users are not able to post answers to this question.

Comment: Any idea if the student has pointed out non-teaching high-income careers that are available to people with a strong math background? My impression was that talented math grads could often command extremely good salaries in a number of areas like finance. In professional settings math grads seem to have quite a bit of freedom with many firms keen to hire them. CS is a reliable career choice but a math degree with some programming knowledge will get your foot in the door to almost any job a CS degree will.

Comment: Sounds like someone from the Philippines.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, I am sorry to tell you that math is not equal to "math".  I do not think you have studied a lot of math. Some basic analysis and algebra together with some applied stochastics and numerics. But that's roughly a first year math course. You're most probably talking about "applied math". Which is a completely different things than pure math. Did you ever calculate something in your course? Or did you just prove things (exclusively!)? If your answer is 1. yes 2. no, you did not have math classes but applied math.

Comment: @Mayou36 of course I had to study and prove a lot of theorems in calculus, discrete mathematics, error correcting codes, algorithms, formal languages, mathematical logic, artificial intelligence and information theory, plus some other minor stuff. Sorry to disappoint you. Is your comment written for the sake of arguing? Also, the OP mentioned that this person won't be able to enroll in any math related course which is clearly impossible when studying CS.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, from what I read I really get the impression that she is interested in pure math. Math is often mistaken as applied math as people think very differently, which matters *IF* she really loves pure math. CS and physics (my field of work) are more of a natural science (we think of 10^1000 being a big number, right?), whereas pure math has a completely different way of thinking. So: math is *not* equal to math. That's my comment. On the courses: sure, but as they belong to the CS, I don't think this is gonna be a problem, only *additional* courses are.

Comment: @Mayou36 it is certainly possible that additional courses will be a problem (probably less than anticipated by her, though, given that a "math inclined" mind is a great asset for studying CS... See Alan Turing) but my first comment was only addressing the "won't be allowed" part.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, I agree, it sounds contradicting, but I would assume, math classes within CS are fine. Otherwise, she would not be able to study a whole bunch of things. Sure, A.T., *the* example from a CS :)

Comment: @Mayou36 I graduated with a CS Major and Math minor. Took classes on number theory, graph theory, abstract algebra, etc. all for elective credit. If you want to do pure math in CS, it is highly feasible.

Comment: @mascoj, of course, but you had math in minor. And I think *that* is what the parents forbid her to do. Not the math courses in CS (which are "surface scratching" for mathematicians by heart) but to take *any additional courses* (like taking a math minor) are the problem. Wouldn't you agree that math courses from the CS Major are significantly different than courses from the Math Minor? (applied calculus vs abstract algebra for example)

Comment: @Mayou36 Absolutely not, generally CS degrees are based upon discrete math and complexity/computability theory which more closely tie to pure math. Sure, it varies from school to school, but my program was largely based around the theory and not application. (i.e. Crypto course was mostly explorations in basic number theory.)

Comment: @mascoj, good example! I remember some colleagues from algebra/analysis mentioning how the hated crypto and number theory when studying as for them, it wasn't "real" math. My point is simple: math and CS are two different studies. Yes, depending on your specialization, there *can be* a rather large overlap, but this is 1. not generally true and 2. most of all not true for the ones who (in my experience) "really love math". Turn around the argument: If someone loves to code, setup servers and so on and she is forced to study math, what would you say? Don't worry, it's the same?

Answer (score 100):

Some thoughts:

- **Suggest counseling**.  They are much more likely to be able to help support her in expressing her goals to her parents, understanding their position, and perhaps in negotiating some sort of compromise with them.  Family relationship issues are likely to be a pretty common concern for college students, and a university counseling service will have had lots of experience with them.
- **Suggest talking to the financial aid office.** They may be able to explore other options for funding if she decides to go on without her parents' financial support, though admittedly there may not be a lot of options for international students.
- **Talk to your contacts at the other university.** See if you can connect her with someone who may be sympathetic to her situation, and who might be able to help her with some of the other things mentioned here.
- **Help her explore degree and course options.** Is there some other degree offered by the institution that might represent a compromise between what she wants and what her parents are willing to pay for?  Are there ways for her to take more classes that she's interested in?
- **She needs to be able to succeed at things even when they don't interest her.**  You write "She couldn't care less about her other courses and her grades".  Regardless of the degree she pursues, this is a recipe for disaster in US academia, where breadth is considered essential and degree requirements are designed accordingly, and overall GPA is widely used as a metric of success,  e.g. for graduate schools and jobs.

  (I am guessing from your terminology that you are in the US.  If not, please correct me.)

  She doesn't have to like all her courses, but she does have to be able to push through and do her best work even in those she dislikes.  That's a necessary academic and life skill, and as a faculty member you may be able to help her develop that skill.  Counseling services may also help with this, if she has some emotional resistance to get past.
- **She might find these courses more interesting if she gives them a chance.** Even pure mathematicians can benefit greatly from knowledge about other fields, and you or other faculty members might be able to help her see connections with things that interest her more.

Comment: I've overstated "couldn't care less." She's aware that the grades are important, though she resents them, and studies hard, but her heart isn't in it. She feels, strongly, the tension between education as a series of hurdles and evaluations and education as learning, and feels like there's only value in the latter. I only know what she's reported about this.

I'm in Canada now, although my vocabulary remains American from force of habit.

These are all great suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: @jdc I’d also add that you could help her to see other career options opened by a mathematics degree, besides teaching. Even if she ultimately wants to be a professor, it’s relatively common to turn a Math PhD into a job as, e.g., a data scientist or analyst of some sorts. Having those as “backup plans” might help to assuage her parents’ fears. Depending on how she wants to play it, she could emphasize those sorts of paths over being a professor. Not pushing back too much if they latch on to those jobs as the goal might let her pursue Math without family strife.

Comment: Fellow Canadian here: University in Canada is *cheap* compared to many other countries and is generally very open in terms of immigration. If she's willing to commit to staying here and start the immigration process she could very easily get scholarships, especially since her parents would be abroad.

Comment: "Even pure mathematicians can benefit greatly from knowledge about other fields" - good programming skills (which she would hopefully learn during her undergrad years in computer science) are very useful to have as an applied mathematician.

Comment: No.1 life lesson I got from college.  "She needs to be able to succeed at things even when they don't interest he"

Answer (score 95):

I have had a small number of students in the same situation over the decades.

My first rule is: Don't get between the student and the parents. That's a complicated and stormy dynamic and I can't do anything but harm there.

My second rule is: Advise the student to cede to the parents for the undergrad degree. To the student, the 4 years of undergrad study seems like a lifetime, but it's really just dust in the wind.  I say, "Suck it up for a couple more years.  In grad school you'll get tuition waived and a stipend and you won't need your parents' support.  Do what they want now.  Do what you want in grad school."

But mostly, don't mess with parental authority.  It's a nuclear volatile area.

Comment: Absolutely!  From the many hints about her home culture, for a professor to contact the parents could be ineffective: “How dare he interfere with our reasoning our daughter!”  Or worse, make things really bad for her: “How could you discuss family business with a foreigner and make us lose face!”

Comment: This started like a great answer, as I absolutely agree with your "first rule". But then the second bit hinted to some outdated ideas (as much as I protest about it, all staff at my institution undergo training on how to deal with student's ... more personal troubles if the situation arises). Telling the student to "suck it up" and "deal with it" comes across as so cold and disinterested. You don't know the situation - it could be anywhere between headstrong parents and psychological abuse, and telling somebody to "suck that up" could mess them up proper in the latter case.

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is, I understand that most of researchers and professors are not qualified nor do they feel comfortable getting into issues like that, especially including parents - and that's perfectly fine. But somebody not just tearing up but "crumpling" before their advisor suggests that they do need help - I think acknowledging that, and maybe steering the them into a direction of somebody who could help and who is qualified to listen to their troubles just sounds like a much better idea than betting on the assumption that that person can take 4 more years of the situation.

Comment: The second point of this answer is probably the worst advice I've read in many years.

Comment: I just don't think that *sucking it up* is *ever* a good advice in any situation, as it solves no problem - especially when it comes to University and career studies: those are the times you must enjoy the most, and the choices that build your personality: sucking it up won't ever do any good, neither to her, nor to her parents (who won't learn the lesson).

Comment: @gented So: 1.  you find that perseverance is "the worst advice", and 2.  the reason seems to be that if one suck's it up, it might interfere with the 4-year party one is entitled to.  "Sucking it up won't ever do any good"?  Seriously?  That's how most of us made it to retirement.

Comment: @B.Goddard 1. that's not even nearly what I said: sucking it up is not equal to perseverance (where did you get that from?). 2. You might consider 4-year of career study a party, I do not consider it so: on the opposite, I believe it is the most formative experience in your life. 3. Don't claim that most people make it to retirement sucking it up - it is just untrue (some may, some may not, it all comes down to how you want to live your life).

Answer (score 52):

This is obviously a very difficult situation that raises tricky issues to do with psychology, parenting, and the sociology of the unnamed country the student is from, which are far above my StackExhange pay grade. I feel rather at a loss to suggest any concrete measures that would tip the scales in the student’s favor in a situation involving such powerful forces of adversity and delicate sociological factors.

However, one thing that I feel may be worth exploring is the student’s parents’ actual state of knowledge regarding the value of a higher education in mathematics. Are they aware that Forbes magazine [declared](http://www.forbes.com/sites/susanadams/2014/04/15/the-best-jobs-for-2014/) “mathematician” to be the number 1 job in the U.S. in 2014? Or that the American Mathematical Society has [a web page](http://www.ams.org/profession/career-info/math-work/math-work) listing many examples of industries employing mathematicians? That page has links to many additional resources touting the virtues of mathematics as a career - for example, [this web page](https://www.bls.gov/ooh/math/mobile/mathematicians-and-statisticians.htm) on the US Bureau of Labor Statistics website, which taught me interesting statistics and facts, such as:

> - The median annual wage for mathematicians was $105,810 in May 2016.
> - Employment of mathematicians is projected to grow 29 percent from 2016 to 2026, much faster than the average for all occupations.

Thus, the one concrete idea I can think of is for either you, the student, or maybe a senior professor at your university (if you are not one yourself) to communicate some of this information to the student’s parents, in writing or over the phone or Skype or maybe even a face to face meeting (if that can be arranged). I would be a bit more understanding if they wanted to discourage their daughter from pursuing an educational track with poor employment prospects (though that would still be sad and tragic from the student’s point of view), but as it happens, math is actually an extremely useful and even lucrative profession these days — so I’m wondering if by giving the parents some actual data about how attractive math can be as a career it just might be possible to persuade them that a comfortable life and their daughter’s personal happiness are not mutually exclusive goals.

In any case, good luck to you and to your student.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it's an excellent one. However, I have a concern. What if the OP's student insists on pursuing _pure_ math all the way and stay in Academia forever? Then the future may not look too good financially.

Comment: @scaaahu there are no guarantees in life. “What if” can work both ways, and she can end up unemployed and bankrupt with a medical or engineering degree as well. Or “what if” she goes into pure math and wins a cushy professorship [and a $100K prize](https://actu.epfl.ch/news/maryna-viazovska-wins-2018-new-horizons-in-mathe-6/) by the age of 34? Or she can just end up as a “normal” mathematics professor - some of us are doing all right, believe it or not. Anyway, glad you liked my answer.

Comment: This answer has a pleasant optimistic outlook to it, though I'm not sure if an objective observer, especially one who was already critical of this argument, would be swayed.  For example, the cited statistics for mathematicians are for 3,100 jobs across the US, and that 29% growth projection is due to an estimate of 4,000 jobs in 2026; it seems unlikely that a critical observer would find those figures to be reassuring.

Comment: @scaaahu then they are, by definition, not in it for the money and will be happy doing what they love at a lower salary. However, that's not something  the student would need to mention to her parents, and dangling this sort of information before them might be enough to convince them that math isn't some sort of dead end career.

Comment: @terdon  That's right, the student may not care about money at all. But, what about her parents? We don't know the student's cultural background. From most westerner's poin of viewt, the student is already an adult. The student doesn't need to care about her parents' thoughts. In some culture, they do.

Comment: @scaaahu that's precisely my point. This is an argument to convince the parents. This shows that, contrary to what they believe, math can offer remuneration.

Comment: It's probably worth finding out if the parents expect the student to return to her country. If so, they won't be swayed by US wages.

Comment: @scaaahu "The student is an adult and doesn't need to care about parents thoughts" Doesn't matter if she's 10 or 60... if her Parents are paying, they get a say in it. Getting a good "return on investment" is a good desire for parents to have. I don't want to spend $200k on an education for my kid to work at Starbucks... this answer (good jobs exist for Mathmaticians) is the answer to that part of the question (Math isn't a good investment).

Comment: You seem to believe that someone would easily renounce their perceptions of reality the moment they see a couple of estimated figures from a website of some obscure agency in another country. To me, this is very naive.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov I don’t “believe” any such thing - where in my answer do I give hints about such a belief? My suggestion may or may not make a difference, and quite likely it won’t. However, it’s the only idea I could come up with, and it seems worth trying. If you have a better suggestion, please post it.

Answer (score 18):

Depending on her mathematical interests, it might be worth looking for career options at the intersection of mathematics and computer science - there's a lot happening there, and some of it even pays quite well ;-)

[My father](https://cecs.anu.edu.au/people/richard-brent) has been a "Professor of Computer Science" for most of his career, but to a large extent he's a mathematician who uses computers as a tool and who applies mathematics to getting more out of computers.

Areas like operations research combine computing and mathematical concepts, and there's high demand for people who can master both.

Comment: Hey, I've implemented a number of algorithms you dad came up with! Please tell your dad a rando on the internet appreciates his work!

Answer (score 15):

1. Computer Science and Math are close already, especially if she chooses  specializations like theoretical computer science. Tell her that many of the subjects can be seen as applied mathematics. And later in work she will probably need at least programming anyways. Other subjects like set theory, logics, signal processing, cryptography, automata and formal languages, complexity theory either contain large amounts of Math or can be useful for a mathematician. I think Math is even one of the biggest reason for CS students to drop out at my University. If she for example takes a Bachelor Thesis topic like cryptography she can do Math for half a year.
2. She can still do a PhD in Math with a Master in CS.
3. She can still study Math after studying CS.
4. She can still study Math in parallel to CS and also online during semester break.
5. In Germany we have a main subject and a "subsubject" ("Nebenfach") where you can take whatever you want with a much smaller amount of hours, is that possible there as well?
6. If all that doesn't help and she really wants to change the subject and it is to expensive to pay for studying on her own she can try to come to Germany where studying is nearly free (around 200 € / semester). There is a "Studienkolleg" where foreigners learn German for a while and then they can attend University.

So I would not try to convice the parents, it sounds as if they have their fixed opinion, but instead try to sidestep the issue and give CS a chance while choosing as many Math or Math-like courses as possible. If you want to support her more, can you give her a job as a teaching assistant or something similar? Also for the relation with their parents I would refer her to student counceling, they will be better trained to help with this sort of problem.

Comment: The asker clearly said that the student will not be allowed to take any more math classes for the remainder of her undergrad studies.

Answer (score 7):

Theoretical Computer Science (and issues like finite automata, formal grammars, complexity theory, graph theory) are mathematics-laden to a degree where they prevent a number of people from making careers in that area.

Many courses labelled "Computer Science" are instead glorified programming courses particular in undergraduate tracks.  If your student focuses on the right kind of courses, she'll have a career in Computer Science involving a whole lot of heavy-duty mathematics.  It may not be kind of "Computer Science" with good job prospects in her home country but may fit the currently prescribed course of action.

Comment: Here are some more "CS" topics she might be interested in: discreet mathematics, the halting problem, the Y-Combinator function (which still hurts my head to contemplate), the Church encoding.  The list goes on.

Answer (score 5):

Seems clear that the relationship between parents and daughter is a major factor, and some answers are missing the fact that this is a bigger thing with her and with her home culture than it would be in USA or Canada.

Her parents may be rightly, or erroneously, trying to do what’s best for her.  Or they may be trying to protect themselves from the embarrassment of having an unsuccessful daughter.

However, **IF** she is willing to risk a break from her parents, might there be someone in Canada who would vouch for her to obtain immigrant status?  My parents are far from wealthy, but their “sponsorship” was enough for a young lady from an Asian country to be allowed to stay.  That’s USA, though, and her parents were not opposed.

Answer (score 4):

Well, life is hard.

I think unless you're able and willing to directly fund her, you can't help her and she'll have to help herself. The main ways to do this would be:

1. Persuade her parents. It sounds like she's given up, in which case you'd probably have even less chance of being successful.
2. Get a loan of some kind, or another scholarship. Your institution (or the new one) might have some scheme to help students facing financial difficulties. Alternatively, there might be a scholarship out there for mathematics students. I did a quick Google search and found [this](https://www.waikato.ac.nz/scholarships/s/mathematics-fees-scholarship); something similar might be available for her.

Having said that there're some caveats. If she breaks with her parents to fund her own education, she'll likely be facing lifelong consequences. This might be culturally acceptable in some countries, but in others, their relationship could be permanently damaged.

The other issue is that if she's completely convinced she wants to be a mathematics researcher, her career path won't be lucrative for quite a while - perhaps until she gets a permanent position. She might have difficulty paying off loans. This is also risky in the sense that if she later realizes how hard it is to get a permanent position in mathematics and / or how different graduate studies is from undergraduate, she might get depressed looking at the student debt she's accrued - all for naught.

On a personal level, I'd suggest she follow her parents' wishes. The risk of permanent damage to their relationship is too high, and besides they have her best interests at heart. She can still have a fulfilling and possibly better-paying career outside of mathematics. You could even show her the compound interest chart and how fast exponential growth is, and suggest that she start saving money after graduation. Eventually, she can fund mathematics research directly. She might not be able to do it herself, but she can still have a direct positive impact on the field.

Comment: I *strongly* disagree with the last paragraph. The damage her parents are doing now may be far greater than the damage of fighting this battle.

Comment: @AustinHenley I suspect we're from different cultural backgrounds then =)

Comment: _Not doing mathematics isn’t the end of the world either._ I find this a very presumptuous and offensive statement. It’s not your place to tell someone else what is or isn’t the end of the world from their perspective, especially when the thing in question is a choice of vocation, which is something that some people feel extremely strongly about. The rest of your answer is sensible and well-written, but I am downvoting because of the last paragraph, and especially the “not the end of the world” statement. I’ll reverse my vote if you make an edit to fix this.

Comment: @DanRomik that could be another cultural thing - I've had people tell me variants of that in genuine earnestness, and reacting in an offended manner would undoubtedly have surprised them - but sure, I removed it.

Comment: Thanks. I removed my downvote, but I still disagree with your last paragraph.

Comment: Very likely to be cultural differences ... for illustration, I know a woman who left home in her 20s to work as a maid in a foreign country. She sent a large chunk of her salary home, which was used to set up her siblings. Her family would constantly ask for more and she would oblige. She effectively gave up her own life and dreams (too old to have children now) for the sake of the family. Against this kind of background, breaking with the family is almost incomprehensible. The consolation for giving up her own life is the ones she helped enable, which might sustain the student here as well.

Comment: _You could even show her the compound interest chart and how fast exponential growth is_ — Seriously? Do you really think explaining exponential growth _to a mathematician_ would do anything other than insult her intelligence?

Comment: @JeffE it's one thing to see exponential functions on paper and another to see it applied in real life. Don't tell me you're not able to explain this to her in a way she'll appreciate and not find insulting, because I'm confident I can. Start by saying "have you seen the compound interest calculations" and if she says yes jump directly to the conclusion; if not show it to her, point out it's an exponential, and then go to the conclusion. How hard can it be?

Comment: @JeffE Knowing mathematics is one thing; applying it to someone else's problem is another thing; applying it to your own situation is yet another thing. The academia.SE is a perfect example of this: even mathematicians sometimes need an advice.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming this is a US question. I would suggest the student a double major: math and economy, CS and economy, for instance. Also, I would suggest to try biasing the subject of the other major towards math applied in economy, which is something banks and overbearing parents love.

Comment: Any reason you're not suggesting math and CS?

Comment: One major is math because she likes it and the other is economy/CS/whatever can convince her parents that she'll bathe in money upon graduation. Economy is useful to some degree if one wants to argue they plan to go in quantitative finance. CS is good for people living in places with lots of IT industry. She'll be tricking her parents, but for the greater good. It's a good training anyway for the moment they'll want to marry her off to someone she doesn't like.

Comment: @Sumyrda sounds like parents have specifically forbidden math, at least when it's explicitly identified as math.

Comment: Per [a comment above](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/102376/my-students-family-wont-let-her-study-what-she-wants/102381#comment267841_102381), this is in Canada.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully I can provide a different outlook here as I’m a CS major trying to get into software development, not an academic. But this question touched me so much I had to answer.

It’s less common, but certainly not impossible to get a job as a software developer as a math major. So she may be able to sell that to her parents. She should tell them that employers will like to see that she did so well in such a hard subject and it will give her an advantage over CS majors (this is probably stretching the truth a bit, but not a complete lie).

I’ve also heard that medical schools and law schools like math majors. But I don’t know enough about either of those to verify if it’s true.

So I would say plan A is for her to try and convince them that there are other things she can do with a math major besides academia.

Plan B would be to find a compromise. Maybe applied math or statistics. From what I understand those are heavy on the math, but a little more practical than pure math.

And if all else fails, CS involves a lot of math too. Especially when you get to the more theoretical side, such as algorithms and language theory. If she’s going to get a masters or phd, that’s even better as she can focus more on the mathematical side and less on the hardware side. Find out if she has any interest in machine learning, data science or artificial intelligence. She may enjoy it more than she thinks.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is what is going to happen in the new school.  If she doesn't study and do well she might as well be defying her parents.

1. She could talk to her parents about taking say 1 extra course in math at the same time as she does her main course.  Offer to pay them back after she graduates. However, this will likely fail as she blew off her other courses and her parents have learned she can't be trusted.  If she had established good faith with her parents by completing the existing courses with good grades this would be an easy sell.

Maybe if she succeeds in the new school this can be revisited.

2. Get a part time job somewhere and pay for her own math classes.  Danger: She has to do well in all her classes or this will back fire.  Her parents will see she failed again, and probably cut her off and bring her home.  Where she will have to take up a terrible job in her own country until she is old enough to strike out on her own.

**Your only hope of changing things is to prove math is a viable career field.  Using actual job listing and a significant body of evidence.**

Another issue is "doesn't hope to return home".  The big question here, is does her parents know,understand, and accept this fact, because it is critical.  Their main argument is that in their own country her math skills will be wasted.  If her parents were to accept this, then she could produce articles from countries she is thinking about moving to on how math and/or teaching is highly valued in that country.

However, "doesn't hope to return home" I am assuming she is there on a student visa or some such permit.  After that expires then what?  Will she have already applied for citizenship in the new country?  Otherwise she will be forced to return to her country.  The citizenship process can be multi-year process, hope doing her homework on this process now.

---

Maybe its time to impress on her how badly thing can get if she doesn't temporarily do what her parents want.  Then if she turns her grades around maybe her parents will be receptive to what she wants.

**We aren't give hardly any cultural information, so I am just making up a worst cast ending.**

She fails, or does not succeed to her parents expectations, they bring her home.  Then what probably no math jobs, and she will be forced to take another job, maybe even a house maid.  Maybe even forced into an arranged marriage, have children and never do math more advance than the math needed for cooking dinner.

I am not a fan of scare tactics, but if she does badly another semester her parent are going to be mad.  They may take action that make her life 10x more miserable than they are now.

Answer (score 2):

I just read the question and realized that it could be quite a specific case if your student is from China. If she is from China, do NOT try to convince her to go against her parents will. I've been teaching thousands of Chinese students and majority of them study what their parents chose for them, not what they want. Their family culture is very complicated. Parent-child bond is pretty much sacred and maintaining it is essential for the child happiness in life.

What I do is usually find a way they can use their passion in the profession that was chosen for them. Math is easy actually, it is used everywhere. She can apply math to any profession. Give her some ideas, examples, advice on math applications in her field. Chinese parents choose professions for their children mostly using two criteria: expected income and lifestyle suitable for their culture. It's not that bad if you think about it.

Comment: FWIW, I noticed that the asker said that the student's parents are doctors and that teachers are looked down upon in her country.  I recently read an unrelated article that stated that Chinese typically see teachers as being on par with doctors, so that would suggest the student's parents are likely from somewhere else, but it's all speculation.  Google Fu: http://www.bbc.com/news/education-24381946

Answer (score 0):

I'd council not getting too involved in family conflicts.

However it sort of sounds like they're of the belief that math can only lead to a job as a math teacher and are trying to push her into a "safe" major.

Perhaps giving the student some tables of income projections by major along with the kinds of jobs they open up might give her something to reassure them with.

Math does pretty well on that score and in her shoes I'd probably be asking "why are you asking me to step down into a (likely) slightly worse-paid, slightly lower status career path? If I was training to become a doctor would you demand I step down to nurse?"

http://www.naceweb.org/job-market/compensation/physics-projected-as-top-paid-class-of-2016-math-and-sciences-major/

Answer (score 0):

With all due respect to her parents and difficult situation, it is she that must do the academic work, and later, practice in a field she finds rewarding. I'd hope her parents wish her to find happiness long term, yet they believe she 'doesn't know what's best'.

There's no easy way to combat this, but here is one potential route:
1) Student states unequivocally her desire for a different path
2) Student proves sincerity by applying for (but not necessarily accepting)  financial aid to render her independent of the parents support.

The parents can then either double down and allow her to incur debt, or back down and let her follow her interests.