# How to Help Commuter Student with problems at home

Tags: ethics

How do I help a student being controlled by his parents? He has a lot of potential but his parents give him projects over schoolwork and discourage him. What role can I play in helping the student?

Comment: Have you consulted with student affairs, or whoever handles that sort of thing for your university?  That would be my first thought to try.

Comment: You need to say more. What is your relationship to the student? To the family? What sort of "projects"?

Answer (score 2):

[Don't get between the student and the parents. That's a complicated and stormy dynamic and [you] can't do anything but harm there.](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/102390/)

You may not like it, but it's really not something to get involved in.